# Visual Studio Code extension host timeout during debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

**What I'm doing**

I am using the instructions on [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world) to generate a Hello World extension for Visual Studio Code. I've generated the extension using Yeoman and am now simply trying to launch the hello world extension in an Extension Host instance of VSCode using the debugger by hitting F5.

**The problem**

I am receiving a notification at the top of the original VSCode window that reads, "Error cannot connect to runtime process (timeout after 3000ms) launch.json | Close".

[image: Here]

This error appears slightly before the Extension Host window opens.

Once the extension host window opens, it spins a bit and then shows this warning at the top of its window:

[image: this warning]

The warning reads, "warn plugin host did not start in 10 seconds, it might be stopped on the first line and needs a debugger to continue | Close".

Seems like I just need some way of making the runtime timeout longer but I haven't found out how to do this.

**My environment:**

- OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite
- Node 0.12.7 or 4.2.1 (I've tried both)
- Visual Studio Code 0.10.1

**EDIT:** This only happens when using Typescript in the Yeoman generator. I tried the Javascript version and it works fine.

Given that this seems to be a bug, I've opened [this Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-generator-code/issues/15) with the code yeoman generator.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple but I spent 1 hour to find the issue.

I think mistake I did is first I created launch json and installed chrome debugger and then I modified launch.json for chrome launch so did not work.

So I tried below and it worked.
Deleted launch.json and reinstalled chrome debugger extension and 
restart visual studio code and create lanch.json after these steps it worked :)

Try it may work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well. I simply reload the extension by pressing `F5` again and it usually works. Rarely it will fail twice in a row and then will work on the third time.

Not really a "solution" to the problem, but it's worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Find %VSCodeHome%\resources\app\extensions\node-debug\out\node\nodeDebug.js and change wait time in line 203.

```
        // try to attach
        setTimeout(function () {
            _this._attach(response, port, 3000);
        }, 2000);
```

into time working for you, like:

```
        // try to attach
        setTimeout(function () {
            _this._attach(response, port, 10000);
        }, 2000);
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the Internet through a proxy may also cause this. It's due to the source map downloader doesn't use your proxy, so the download always times out after attempting to connect for a long time.

For those who encounter this, try the workaround [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug-core/issues/262#issuecomment-453043553).

Answer (score -1):

I am also running into this same error, but I'm seeing this with the example language server example repo that's in the documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node-example